# Adding an icon into WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, icons

I want to adding an icon in each row of my datagrid. the columns are generated automatically and i have added an column with a datagridtemplatecolumn to show an icon in the first column.

this is my xaml code to show the icon:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding User.myDataTable}" IsReadOnly="True" FrozenColumnCount="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="IconHeader"  Header="" CanUserResize="False">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="myImage" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

that works well.
now i want to change the icon if in one column of the row is a condition is true.
for example. if column 11 is value "true" then icon 1 and if value "false" then icon2.

can i use the loadingrow event from the datagrid to do this and how can i do this with mvvm? or is there another way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do here is use a DataTrigger in your CellTemplate that will fire based on a binding to the column data:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Source="myImage1" x:Name="img" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=[11]}" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="myImage2" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

DataRow has both int and string indexers for getting a column by index or name so for your binding path you can use `[]` with either the column index (`[3]`) or the column name (`[MyColumn]`).

Comment: how can i do the binding to the column11property? my columns are generated automatically.

Comment: That's a placeholder for the boolean property that you want to use to determine which image to use since your question didn't show any of the data.

Comment: my data came from a storedprocedure from MSSQL Server. in my model i have a datatable that is filled by the storedprocedure and this datatable is bind to the itemssource of the datagrid. so i don't know how to make the decision between image 1 or 2

Comment: Updated binding path for DataRow.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for converters. Just bind the Source-property of your Image to the Property you want:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=BoolProp, Converter={StaticResource BoolToImageConv}}"
```

Your converter could look like

```
public class BoolToImageConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public string FalsePath { get; set; }
    public string TruePath { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value))
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(TruePath));
        }
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(FalsePath));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the resources of your Window/UserControl you have to refer your Converter.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <conv:BoolToImageConverter FalsePath="pathforimageiffalse" TruePath="pathforimageiftrue" x:Key="BoolToImageConv"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: can you tell me how i must add the xmlns namespace in my window?

Comment: Of course: `xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:ApplicationName.FolderName"` And if its in another Assembly: `xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:ApllicationName.FolderName;assembly=AssemblyName"`...But just type xmlns:conv=" and intellisense should do the rest^^

Comment: sorry but i must to ask again: i have added a class BoolToImageConverter in an Folder Converter. now i have add to the namespace xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:WPF.Converter" but the conv:BoolToImageConverter is not in the namespace. whats wrong?

Comment: Try to compile it, sometimes the VS-Debugger is a little bit slow^^

Comment: Check out the namespace of your converter. It has to be `WPF.Converter`.

Comment: the namespace is the same. Intellisense also knows the BooltoImageConverter class when i write "conv:" and it knows the properties FalsePath and Truepath but the compiler say that the BooltoImageConverter is not in the namespace WPF.Converter. I'm confused

Comment: <Window x:Class="WPF.User"
        xml:lang="de-DE"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:WPF.Converter"
        Title="User" Height="400" Width="900" ShowInTaskbar="False">
<Window.Resources>
        <conv:BoolToImageConverter TruePath="" FalsePath="" x:Key="BoolToImageConv"></conv:BoolToImageConverter>
    </Window.Resources>

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way would be to implement a IValueConverter. If column11 is true, show the one image, if it's false, then show the other image.

IValueConverter : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx

Something like :

```
public class IconConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     if ((bool)value == true)
     {
        // column11 = true, so show icon 1
        return image1;
     }
     else
     {
        return image2;
     }
  }
}
```